# JavaScript set value for variable failed

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk

I'm new to javascript. I'm trying to set value to variable with the following code but failed. Someone please help point out what is wrong with my code.

When I try to print out the value of variable "deviceLatitude", it give me "undefined". But if I print the value from inside the function, it give me the correct value. What have I done wrong?

The reason I need to have global variable for this value is because I need to use it in later stage such as compare distance with different location as needed.

```
var deviceLatitude;
var deviceLongitude;
function suc (p) {
     deviceLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
     deviceLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
     // alert(deviceLatitude);
}
intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(suc);
alert(deviceLatitude);
```

Comment: Where do you call that function? Since you do not call it the value of that variable is in fact undefined.

Comment: @SVSchmidt the function is called as a callback by `intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: Yes, the fucntion "suc" is called by "intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition". @torazaburo, I have defined the variable outside of the function, I just add the value into it, is that wrong? Please advice.

Comment: and why my question been vote down? person who vote down can explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @torazaburo, it's not possible to get data of asynchronously function out  into global variable.

But to achieve what is needed, a workaround can handle that. Since this is HTML5 app, one can use localStorage to save the value and access it anytime later from other screen/function.

A simple example code will be as below:

```
intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            function(p) {
                if (p.coords.latitude != undefined) {
                    localStorage.deviceLatitude = p.coords.latitude;
                    localStorage.deviceLongitude = p.coords.longitude;
                }
            },
            function() { 
                alert("geolocation failed"); 
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

`suc` is being called back asynchronously, so when you issue the alert after the call to `intel.xdk....`, `suc` hasn't been called yet.

Note the documentation, my emphasis:

> Use this command to get the current location. This command
>   **asynchronously** acquires the approximate latitude and longitude of the
>   device. When data is available, the success function is called. If
>   there is an error getting position data, the error function is called.

Therefore, if you want to do something with `deviceLatitude`, you'll have to do it *inside* the callback.

If you're a promises type of guy, you could do:

```
function getCurrentPosition() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(resolve, reject);
  });
}

getCurrentPosition.then(
  function(p) {
    //do something with p.coords.latitude
  },
  function() {
    //something went wrong
  }
 );
```

Comment: Is there anyway to bring the value out as global variable?

Comment: No, you cannot bring it out as a global variable until it has been set. :-)

Comment: Actually I get it work to do what I need such as calculate distance and set the value into the HTML and etc inside the function. Just hope I can set the value to global and I can use the variable as I need. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to make anonymous function for success and other for error.
Then create another function which will be called by async when data is available.

```
function overrideLocalStore(lat, log)
{
    alert("lat"+lat+" long"+long);
    localStorage.setItem("deviceLatitude", lat);
    localStorage.setItem("deviceLongitude", log);
}

intel.xdk.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    function(p)
    {
        alert("geolocation success");
        if (p.coords.latitude != undefined)
            overrideLocalStore(p.coords.latitude, p.coords.longitude);
    },
    function()
    { 
        alert("geolocation failed"); 
        getLocation();
    }
);

// Use whatever you need
alert(localStorage.getItem("deviceLatitude"));
alert(localStorage.getItem("deviceLongitude"));
```

Comment: Hi @LXSoft, thanks, I tried that too. It's not working. When I try to print the variable outside of the callback function I still get "undefined" .

Comment: Can you to try to store in session object? From ovverideGlobals function? Then you can access the variable in the store object, it is weird I worked in a problem same as you, but with Google Maps API I stored it in a session variable.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks for giving me such idea. I write it to localstorage and success. Thank you so much. Now I can use the value anywhere I want.

Comment: UPDATED. Glad to help you!

Comment: I did not create the localStorage in the beginning. I just create the localStorage inside the callback function. Also did not call another function to set the localStorage as I don't see it require.

Comment: It is fine then, update your post with working method, seems to be a lot of problems as that, so your post can help other people in this comunity. Or select a working example. Thanks